# Want to Clear select query and add insert query after that

Tags: mysql

My query is below

```
select count(*) from users where 1=1 and (username like '%abc%');
```

I want this query but want to add an record with this like below

```
select count(*) from users where 1=1 and (username like '%abc%') INSERT INTO users (username,email,phone)VALUES (abc,abc@xyz.com,123456789);
```

Comment: What's the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: dear i want isert data into select query like
select count(*) from users where 1=1 and (username like '%abc%') 
/* connection with previous query should not break then insert an record */
INSERT INTO users (username,email,phone)VALUES (abc,abc@xyz.com,123456789);

Comment: That just repeats what it says in the question, which doesn't make sense. What you have here is a query, with a redundant `1=1` clause, and an update statement that doesn't have anything do to with the query. This is two SQL statements, no two ways about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of `where 1=1` is useless. You simply need:

```
select count(*) from users where username like '%abc%';
```

Second you can't mix getting data out (`SELECT`) and adding data (`INSERT`). 
Those 2 statements *HAVE* TO be separate.

The logic is not obvious what you are trying to achieve. It's a good idea to explain what you want to do and we can propose the solution. Sometimes explaing the problem clears obstacles.